# Caffe training error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: segmentation-fault, caffe, pycaffe

What is this segmentation fault is happening when I am trying to run the training in pycaffe?

```
I0719 07:48:27.317548 23202 upgrade_proto.cpp:1106] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated 'solver_type' field (enum)': solver.prototxt
I0719 07:48:27.317767 23202 upgrade_proto.cpp:1113] Successfully upgraded file specified using deprecated 'solver_type' field (enum) to 'type' field (string).
W0719 07:48:27.317807 23202 upgrade_proto.cpp:1115] Note that future Caffe releases will only support 'type' field (string) for a solver's type.
*** Aborted at 1531957707 (unix time) try "date -d @1531957707" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7f649a52a512 cfree
*** SIGSEGV (@0x6) received by PID 23202 (TID 0x7f649cfda1c0) from PID 6; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f649a4db4b0 (unknown)
    @     0x7f649a52a512 cfree
    @     0x7f649c5fbaa8 caffe::UpgradeSnapshotPrefixProperty()
    @     0x7f649c5fc3d0 caffe::ReadSolverParamsFromTextFileOrDie()
    @           0x41294a train()
    @           0x410c7f main
    @     0x7f649a4c6830 __libc_start_main
    @           0x4115a9 _start
    @                0x0 (unknown)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

> What is this segmentation fault

This is a heap corruption bug of some sort.

You should report this to developers of `caffe`. Running this program under valgrind may provide additional info.